# Kate's Toolbar is Missing

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kate

In Kubuntu 19.10, how do you get this tool bar to show in [Kate](https://kate-editor.org/)? :

[image]

For example, you can see that my default installation of Kate is missing that toolbar:

[image]

Comment: Settings > Show toolbar works for me in 19.10 with Kate 19.12.2.

Comment: And to toggle the visibility of the menu bar which has *File, Edit, View, Projects, Bookmarks, Sessions, Tools, Settings, Help* use `Ctrl+M`. But maybe you just need to click on ☰, the fourth button from the left in your image.

Comment: @DKBose - Yes, that works. Thank you! However, I just noticed that it doesn't persist after closing and relaunching [Kate](https://kate-editor.org/). Do you know how to make that preference (of showing that toolbar always) persist between sessions?

Comment: The default for me is to have such changes persist. Please try this: `Settings > Configure Kate > Sessions`. In there, see that under `Session Elements`, `Include Window Configuration` is checked.

Comment: @DKBose : Hmm, that was [already checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdtGk.png). However, when I choose "Load last used session" or "Start new session", instead of "Manually choose a session", the toolbar is there after a relaunch. If you want to answer my question formally, I'll check it. Thanks again.

Comment: It works for me even I if set "Load empty session" which is my preference so I'm not really sure what's going on. So if you've found a satisfactory solution for your usage, please post an answer yourself.

Comment: @DKBose Ok, done.

Answer (score 1):

As `DK Bose` commented, the toolbar can be shown by going to the settings menu and then toggling on "Show Toolbar".

After doing this, though, the Toolbar would only be there during that session; I had to repeat that "toggling on" each kate-launch.

Perhaps its a bug, but after going to `Settings > Configure Kate > Sessions` and toggling between the settings below (and applying them), the inability to persist my "Show Toolbar" preference went away.

Initially, my selected behavior, on Application Startup, was "Manually choose a session".

As you can see below, I ultimately chose "Load last used session". After this, indirectly, the preference of "Show Toolbar" persisted to subsequent launches:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I think one difference for what I see and you see is that I don't use sessions at all. If you click on *Help > Kate Handbook* there's a little bit on Sessions and that mentions that window configs are tied to each session. I also noticed, in the image in your question, that you had `Untitled * --- Kate <2>`. The way I use Kate is to have just one window with tabs for additional files instead of having a new window. I'm not saying that my way is better but I'm just trying to understand why we see different things!